# access dynamic session variable in all views codeigniter

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and what i want to do is when user logs in, I am storing his first name and last name in session.

i have header file which i include in all the views
i want to show something like this
welcome "amit patil" | Logout

where "amit patil" is coming from session.

- How can i access session value and display in header file
- I know it can be possible with this

  ```
  $data['admin_fname'] = $this->session->userdata("first_name");

  $this->load->view("header",$data);
  ```
- I dont want to repeat this process in all the controllers, Is there any easy way ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) to do it.

```
function getUserFirstName() {
     $ci =& get_instance();
     return $ci->session->userdata("first_name");
}
```

And then load the helper with `$this->load->helper()` in your controller. If something related to your user changes you will need to change only in the helper.